# Regular expression in python with variable strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the foll. strings in python:

```
Vladimir_SW_crop_mask_ERA.hdr
Ust_Ordynskiy_Buryatskiy_AO_SW_crop_mask_ERA.hdr
Ingush_WW_crop_mask.dat
```

I want to parse these strings such that:

1. Get the crop type which can be either SW or WW
2. Get the region name which is the text preceding _SW or _WW

I was doing str.split('_')[0] to get region name, but that fails in case of `Ust_Ordynskiy_Buryatskiy_AO_SW_crop_mask_ERA.hdr`, where the region name is `Ust_Ordynskiy_Buryatskiy_AO`

Comment: regexes would'nt make too much sense on constant strings :)

Comment: thanks @Jasper, it is a bad name for the question :) but 'regular expression in python' was already asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [partition](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition) and [rpartition](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.rpartition) to do this:

```
>>> s = 'Vladimir_SW_crop_mask_ERA.hdr'
>>> s.partition('_crop')[0].rpartition('_')[::2]
('Vladimir', 'SW')
>>> s = 'Ust_Ordynskiy_Buryatskiy_AO_SW_crop_mask_ERA.hdr'
>>> s.partition('_crop')[0].rpartition('_')[::2]
('Ust_Ordynskiy_Buryatskiy_AO', 'SW')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regexp should work:

```
(.*)_(SW|WW)
```

Match everything up to an underscore followed by either `SW` or `WW` and put this in the first matching group and the following `SW` or `WW` in the second group:

```
import re

strs = ["Vladimir_SW_crop_mask_ERA.hdr",
        "Ust_Ordynskiy_Buryatskiy_AO_SW_crop_mask_ERA.hdr",
        "Ingush_WW_crop_mask.dat"]

for s in strs:
    print(re.match("(.*)_(SW|WW)", s).groups())
```

Result:

```
('Vladimir', 'SW')
('Ust_Ordynskiy_Buryatskiy_AO', 'SW')
('Ingush', 'WW')
```